Multisite redirect
I am using WordPress multisite, I want user when they login for the first time, they get redirected to a certain dashboard inside the panel instead of going to WordPress dashboard. How to do that?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

@Community Seems clear enough to me?

Where is this dashboard? When you say 'in the panel' do you mean not inside the normal WordPress dashboard? I'm not sure it matters though.
